# Ошибка в функции метода секущих, язык си

Tags: c

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Происходит зацикливания в функции secu. Функция fun необходима для того, чтобы искать её корень с помощью функции secu. a = -1, b = 2. Помогите найти ошибку.

Comment: Вам будет очень удобно набирать код ответа, если вам его дадут картинкой?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов О! А это идея! :)

Comment: @Harry Главное кода побольше написать, да идентификаторы подлиннее ;-)

Comment: Потрудитесь ответить (себе для начала), что будет делать ваш код при `fun(x) == 0`?

Answer (score 1):

Я вам уже в комментарии написал: у вас нет ветви для `fun(x) == 0`. Поэтому при первой же итерации вы, получив `x==1` и `fun(x) == 0`, получаете бесконечный цикл, в котором `a` и `b` не меняются.